# How to fix 'Settings' object has no attribute 'CASSANDRA_FALLBACK_ORDER_BY_PYTHON'

Tags: django

I'm setting cassandra engine in django project, I successfully run server but when I click model of myapp in admin site I got error:

```
Settings' object has no attribute 'CASSANDRA_FALLBACK_ORDER_BY_PYTHON
```

I first sync cassandra then migrate it,after that i runserver there are no error but in admin site when i want to put data in my model got this error

```
For database I use django_cassandra_engine 

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'TEST_NAME': 'Test Cluster',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1 ',
        'POST': '9042',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'replication': {
                'strategy_class': 'SimpleStrategy',
                'replication_factor': 1
            },
            'connection': {
                'consistency': ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE,
                'retry_connect': True
                # + All connection options for cassandra.cluster.Cluster()
            },
            'session': {
                'default_timeout': 10,
                'default_fetch_size': 10000
                # + All options for cassandra.cluster.Session()
            }
        }
}
```

And I have model like this:

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from django_cassandra_engine.models import DjangoCassandraModel

class mymodel(DjangoCassandraModel):
    name = columns.Text(required=True)
    phone = columns.Integer(primary_key=True)

in my terminal i get 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django_cassandra_engine/models/__init__.py", line 745, in order_by
    *self._get_ordering_condition(col))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 1133, in _get_ordering_condition
    raise QueryException("Can't resolve the column name: '{0}'".format(colname))
cassandra.cqlengine.query.QueryException: Can't resolve the column name: 'pk'


  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'CASSANDRA_FALLBACK_ORDER_BY_PYTHON'
```

I also use rest_framework for api view 
How to solve this type of problem

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your settings:

```
CASSANDRA_FALLBACK_ORDER_BY_PYTHON = True
```